# When are transactions commited with JEE JPA (EclipseLink 2.0)?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, eclipselink, commit

When are transactions committed with JPA (EclipseLink 2.0)?

This is my problem:

```
public void methodA()
{
    while(something)
    {
       methodB();
    }
}

public void methodB()
{
   //Insert new client into Client table.
}
```

Let's say it takes 10 minutes for `methodA` to be completed. If I peek the database's Client table while `methodA` runs, I can't see any row. This means after `methodB` ends, the transaction is not committed. But if I wait until `methodA` finishes, then the clients appear in the database.

I want every transaction to be committed after `methodB` ends. How can I do this?

**EDIT**: I want the application container (Glassfish) to take care of the "commit". I don't want to do this by calling the Entity Manager. I'm looking for something such as an annotation above `methodB()`. Both methods are inside a singleton bean.

Comment: where have you put your transaction definition/demarcation? Clearly anybody can call em.getTransaction() and commit it if using a local transaction

Comment: I don't want to commit myself. I want the application container to take care of it (Glassfish 3.1.2.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Stateless EJB beans, transaction is commited when leaving EJB (by default).

Put methodB() in separate EJB.(assuming methodA() is not EJB)

Comment: Jmmm I guess this could be a solution... But it would drastically affect my design. Isn't there a more elegant way to do this? Maybe with an annotation above methodB?

Comment: @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) method anotation. But new transaction is created only when calling it from other class then "this.".